# How do I Create Automated UI test code for application developed using Domain-Driven-Design with very little concrete UI requirements?

Tags: testing, domain-driven-design, ui, test-automation, selenium

We are developing an application using Domain-Driven-Design(DDD).

We have to come up with Automated UI Test code.

The customer has used 3rd-party GUI Administration template (https://bootstraphunter.com/smartadmin-product.php) so that the GUI can be configured for the most part using the aforementioned 3rd-party tool.

For Automated UI Testing, I'm going to use NUnit with Selenium because I have experience using the said tools.

Sadly,  the specifics about the Business-Side is left out.

In other words, customers has Not provided us with any use-cases or use case diagrams.

So far, a lot of the backend development(database stuff) deals with Generating New tables using Code-Generation Tools.

This basically suggests that the Customer is creating specific development tools for the application.  As time goes on, I feel that the customer will configure the development tools to generate code and/or database tables.

Since a lot of the Business-specific requirements are vague, the customers communicates with our GUI development team to discuss how some module should be configured, but the problem is that I end up creating the Automated test code after the GUI module development is complete which is kind of pointless.

What steps should I take to make my Automated UI testing be significant in terms of usefulness in the development of the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with bad/incomplete/unclear specifications?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40676/dealing-with-bad-incomplete-unclear-specifications)

Comment: @gnat: that other question is clearly not a duplicate (nothing about automated unit tests in there, and completely different focus), and I see no reason to edit the question above to make this any clearer.

Comment: @DocBrown upon re-reading both questions, your reasoning looks compelling (retracted my vote)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point in time, someone *has* to make a decision how the UI has to look like. If this is done iteratively step-by-step in a dicussion between the customer and your team, fine - that is a feasible, pragmatic way. Whenever the decision is made for a particular part of your UI, you can start creating the tests.

> I end up creating the Automated test code after the GUI module development is complete which is kind of pointless

Why do you think this is pointless? Automated tests are *primarily* regression tests,  verifying your application Version 2.0 still works like Version 1.0, after you added some new features. If you need tests only once or twice to to verify a written spec, it would be pointless to automate them, since it would most probably be much more efficient to do the tests manually.